# Hom is a left-exact functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

> If 
>   $$
> 0 \to A \to B\to C,$$ 
>   is a left exact sequence of $R$-module, then for any $R$-module $M$, 
>   $$
> 0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,A)\to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,B)\to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,C),
> $$ 
>   is left exact.

I proved the above, and highlighted what I'm a little unfamiliar with: Let $$
0 \to A\ \xrightarrow{i}\ B\ \xrightarrow{f}\ C,
$$ 
and 
$$
0 \to \operatorname{Hom}(M,A)\ \xrightarrow{\operatorname{Hom}(M,i)}\ \operatorname{Hom}(M,B)\ \xrightarrow{\operatorname{Hom}(M,f)}\ \operatorname{Hom}(M,C).
$$ 
We need to show that 
$$
\ker\left(\operatorname{Hom}(M,f)\right)=\operatorname{Hom}(M,i)(\operatorname{Hom}(M,A)).
$$

Let $i \circ \varphi \in \operatorname{RHS}$. Then $f \circ i \circ \varphi : M \to C$ is $0$ since $f \circ i \circ \varphi(M) \subseteq f( i(A)) = f(\ker(f))=0$.

Conversely, let $\psi \in \operatorname{LHS}$. Then $f \circ \psi = 0$ so that $ f(\psi(M))=0$. Hence $\psi(M) \subseteq \ker(f)=i(A)$. **Since the image of $\psi$ is contained in the image of $i$, we may factor $\psi$ as $\psi=i \varphi$ with $\varphi : M \to A$.** (Here is my trial, but I'm not fully understanding this: Since $i$ is injective, $i(A)$ is isomorphic with $A$. So $i^{-1}(\psi (M)) \subseteq A$ and if we let $\varphi=i^{-1} \psi$, then $\psi = i \varphi$.)

And I have one more question: The above looks very messy, especially the notation. Is there a better proof/understanding about it?

Comment: Re: notation. Why not use $i_{\ast}$ and $f_{\ast}$ instead of $Hom_{R}(M,i)$ and $Hom_{R}(M,f)$?

Comment: This is supposed to follow from the fact that $\text{Hom}(-, A)$ preserves limits, but I am not sure about the details.

Comment: If $N$ is an $A$-module, then we can consider the functors (from the category of $A$-modules to itself) $M\to M\otimes N$ and $P\to \text{Hom}(N,P)$ which we denote by $T$ and $U$, respectively. We then have $\text{Hom}(T(M),P)=\text{Hom}(M,U(P))$. In particular, we say that $U$ is a $\textbf{right adjoint}$ of $T$. It is a general fact that any functor which is a right adjoint is left exact. Therefore, $U$ is a left exact functor.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that a proof that every right adjoint functor is left exact (in this case) relies on the result stated in your question. Therefore, I suppose that I am just talking (abstract) nonsense...

Comment: @Amitesh: You can get exactness of $\operatorname{Hom}$ from Yoneda, if you want to talk abstract nonsense. No adjointness needed here, but it boils down to what I'm saying below.

Comment: Dear Theo, my line of thought was based on the idea that one can establish the right exactness of the tensor product using the fact that it is a left adjoint. However, trying to work the other way (i.e., establishing the left exactness of "Hom" using the fact that it is a right adjoint) does indeed seem inconsequential.

Comment: @Amitesh: yes, that's indeed true. In fact, you can get the left exactness from abstract nonsense simply by recalling what the definition of a limit means and saying $\operatorname{Hom}(M,-)$ preserves limits *tautologically*.

Comment: Dear Gobi, Theo's explanation  below is (as usual) very helpful. I think it is also worth emphasizing that this is *very* important: in fact, it is essentially the definition of exactness  of such a sequence in an abelian category! Or, restated, it is the universal property of the kernel: a map $X \to B$ factors through $A$ if and only if the composite $X \to  B \to C$ is zero (and then the factorization through $A$ is unique).

Comment: @AkhilMathew How does the post below show left-exact in (1) without showing $\ker \subset Im$ and $Im \subset \ker$?

Comment: @Gobi for the record, since no one commented on the argument in bold that you specifically asked about, let me say that it's not true in general that when a map $\psi$ lands in the image of a map $i$, therefore it follows that $\psi$ factors through $i$, $\psi = i\phi$. For example $\text{id}\colon \mathbb{Z}/2\to \mathbb{Z}/2$ lands in the image of $i\colon\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2$ but obviously $\psi$ cannot factor through $i$.

Comment: But does the argument work at least when $i$ is monomorphism, as you have argued? Yes, then I think it works. In any abelian category it is true that the domain of a monomorphism is isomorphic to its image, and you can get the factorization that way. But I agree with the other comments that arguing via the universal property of kernels is conceptually simpler and easier to understand. And more general, since Hom(X,-) being left-exact holds in any category, whereas the argument about monomorphism being isomorphic to images does not.

Comment: @AlJebr but the post by t.b. does show exactly that $\ker j_* \subseteq \text{im} i_*$ and $\text{im} \subseteq \ker j_*$. It's not clear what you're asking...?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well, your proof is okay. Let me suggest a slightly different way of looking at it:

Consider a sequence

$$ 0\; \xrightarrow{\phantom{ij}} \; A \; \xrightarrow{i\phantom{j}}\; B\; \xrightarrow{j\phantom{i}} \; C$$
and look at
$$ 0\; \xrightarrow{\phantom{j_{\ast}}}
\operatorname{Hom}{(M,A)}\; \xrightarrow{i_{\ast}}\operatorname{Hom}{(M,B)} \;\xrightarrow{j_{\ast}}\;
\operatorname{Hom}{(M,C)},$$
where I write $i_{\ast} = \operatorname{Hom}(M,i)$ and $j_{\ast} =  \operatorname{Hom}(M,j)$.

Saying that the first sequence is exact amounts to saying $i = \ker{j}$, that is $ji = 0$ and $i$ has the universal property as depicted in the first diagram below: If $g: M \to B$ is such that $jg = 0$ then there exists a unique $f: M \to A$ such that $if = g$. In other words if $j_\ast g = 0$ then $g = i_{\ast}f$, or yet again $\operatorname{Ker}{j_\ast} \subset \operatorname{Im}{i_{\ast}}$ **and** $i_{\ast}$ is injective.

[image: property kernel/cokernel]

On the other hand, the second diagram says: if $g: M \to B$ is of the form $g = if = i_{\ast}f$ then $j_{\ast}g = 0$ (because $j_\ast g = j_{\ast}i_{\ast} f = (ji)_{\ast}f = 0f = 0$). In other words, $\operatorname{Im}{i_{\ast}} \subset \operatorname{Ker}{j_{\ast}}$.

Summing up, we have shown that for all $M$ the sequence

$$ 0\; \xrightarrow{\phantom{j_{\ast}}}
\operatorname{Hom}{(M,A)}\; \xrightarrow{i_{\ast}}\operatorname{Hom}{(M,B)} \;\xrightarrow{j_{\ast}}\;
\operatorname{Hom}{(M,C)}$$
is exact both at $\operatorname{Hom}{(M,A)}$ ($i_{\ast}$ is injective) and at $\operatorname{Hom}{(M,B)}$ ($\operatorname{Im}{i_{\ast}} = \operatorname{Ker}{j_{\ast}}$)—you seem to have forgotten about the first point here.

---

**Added:** As witnessed by the argument above, left exactness of $\operatorname{Hom}$ *is essentially the definition of left exactness* in the [abelian category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category) of $R$-modules. As the comments try to point out, the importance of this fact cannot be overemphasized.

I would like to add two further points:

1. A functor $F$ is left exact in your definition if and only if $0 \to F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C)$ is left exact for every *short exact* sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$. 
    Indeed, in a left exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C$, we may factor $j: B \to C$ over its image as $B \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Im}{j} \rightarrowtail C$ and obtain two *exact* sequences $$0 \to A \to B \to \operatorname{Im}{j} \to 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0 \to \operatorname{Im}{j} \to C \to \operatorname{Coker}{j} \to 0.$$ Applying $F$ to these two exact sequences, we obtain the left exact sequences $$0 \to F(A) \to F(B) \to F(\operatorname{Im}{j}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0 \to F(\operatorname{Im}{j}) \to F(C ) \to F(\operatorname{Coker}{j}).$$ Since the kernel of a map is not changed by postcomposing the map with a monomorphism (check this!), we have $$\operatorname{Ker}{(F(B) \to F(\operatorname{Im}{j}))} = \operatorname{Ker}{(F(B) \to F(\operatorname{Im}{j}) \to F(C))},$$ so by functoriality of $F$ we get a left exact sequence $0 \to F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C)$ as desired.
2. A natural question is: When does $\operatorname{Hom}(M,-)$ send short exact sequences to short exact sequences? In other words, when is $j_\ast = \operatorname{Hom}{(M,j)}$ an epimorphism for all short exact sequences $0\; \xrightarrow{\phantom{ij}} \; A \; \xrightarrow{i\phantom{j}}\; B\; \xrightarrow{j\phantom{i}} \; C \to 0$? 
   In view of left exactness of $\operatorname{Hom}{(M,-)}$ the question is: Given any morphism $h: M \to C$ and any epimorphism $j: B \to C$, when is $h$ of the form $h = j_\ast g$ for some morphism $g: M \to B$? 

   [image: Lifting property]

   As you certainly know, this is precisely the definition of *[projective modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module)*: $M$ is called projective if and only if $g$ always exists, for all epimorphisms $j: B \twoheadrightarrow C$ and all $h: M \to C$. For emphasis:

   > A module $M$ is *projective* if and only if $\operatorname{Hom}{(M,-)}$ is *exact*, that is: it sends short exact sequences to short exact sequences.

Comment: The half-exactness of Hom is the essential "practical" ingredient in proof by a ("small") Yoneda's lemma of the (suitable) half-exactness of left/right adjoint functors.

Comment: How are we showing left-exact in $(1)$ without showing $\ker \subset Im$ and $Im \subset \ker$?

Comment: @AlJebr If you look right at the end of the third paragraph of this answer, you will see that t.b. does conclude that $\ker j_* \subseteq \text{im} i_*$. And if you look at the end very next paragraph, you find $\text{im} \subseteq \ker j_*$