# Is $h^*$ injective in this case?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Let $N$ and $N'$ be finite rank free $\mathbb Z$-modules. Let $M=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z \text{-mod}}(N,\mathbb Z)$ and $M'=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z \text{-mod}}(N',\mathbb Z)$ .

Suppose I am given a $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism $h:N\rightarrow N'$. Then I can define a map $h^*:M'\rightarrow M$ by $m\mapsto m\circ h$ .

**If $h$ has finite cokernel then is it true that $h^*$ is injective?**

My attempt -

$\ker h^*=\{f:f\circ h = 0\}$ where $0$ here is the map that sends everything to $0\in\mathbb Z$. Then is it obvious that $f$ is the zero map? I was thinking $f\circ h=0\Rightarrow f\circ h(x)=f(x)h(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb Z$. Since $\mathbb Z$ is an integarl domain this means that one among $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ must be $0$. But suppose for some $x$ if $h(x)=0$ then it could happen that $f(x)\neq0$ so that means $f$ need not be the zero map. Also I am not sure how to use the finiteness of cokernel. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

**EDIT** I just realised that I wrote the composition $f\circ h$ as the pointwise product which is wrong. So now I am completely stumped on how to prove $f$ is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $$N\stackrel{h}\to N'\stackrel{\pi}\to\operatorname{Coker}h\to0$$ is exact, so $$0\to \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Coker}h,\mathbb Z) \stackrel{\pi^*}{\to}\operatorname{Hom}(N',\mathbb Z)\stackrel{h^*}{\to} \operatorname{Hom}(N,\mathbb Z)$$ is also exact; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200021/m-to-m-to-m-to-0-exact-implies-0-to-texthomm-n-to-texthomm). But $\operatorname{Coker}h$ is a finite abelian group, so $\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Coker}h,\mathbb Z)=0$. Then $\ker h^*=\operatorname{Im} \pi^*=0$.

Comment: I don't understand the statement Hom(finite abelian group, $\mathbb Z$) =0. I can only say that the Cokernel is the direct sum of finitely many cyclic groups. Then what?

Comment: @Rise In your question it is written: "If $h$ has finite cokernel...". What is this supposed to mean? (Btw, a *finite* direct sum of finitely many cyclic groups must be a finite group, unless you assume that the direct sum contains some copies of $\mathbb Z$.)

Comment: it means the Cokernel is a finite set. OK let's forget what I said about finite direct sum. Can you give me a hint to prove Hom(cokernel $h, \mathbb Z$) = 0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rise If $(G,+)$ is a finite group, $n=|G|$, and $f:G\to\mathbb Z$ is a group homomorphism, then $nf(x)=f(nx)=f(0)=0\implies f(x)=0$ for all $x\in G$. ($nx=0$ follows from [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications).)

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $h^{*}$ acts on hom sets. By the Yoneda Lemma, that each $h:N\rightarrow N'$ induces a natural transformation $h^{*}:[N',-]\rightarrow [N,-]$ defined by $h^{*}(m:N'\rightarrow M)=m\circ h$.

Then, it is not hard to show that $h^{*}$ is monic (injective) iff $h$ is epic (surjective).