# Hom(G,-) functor is exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra

Given an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ we know that the induced sequence $0 \rightarrow Hom(G,A)\rightarrow Hom(G,B)\rightarrow Hom(G,C)$ is exact. But wouldn't the last homomorphism be onto since functors preserve injectivivity and surjectivity? And thus you could extend the sequence by $Hom(G,C) \rightarrow 0$ and preserve exactness? It would follow that $Hom(G,-)$ is exact. What is my mistake?

Comment: Functors do not necessarily preserve monomorphisms nor epimorphisms. In fact, the most commonly encountered classes of functors that have that property are the left exact and right exact functors respectively.

Comment: I understand this, but functors on the category of groups preserve epi and mono-morphisms no (since epi and monomorphism is equivalent with surjective and injective)? (I also corrected my mistake and replaced Hom(-,G) with Hom(G,-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is when you say that functors preserve injectivity and surjectivity. That is certainly not true for general functors, and even representable covariant functors $X\mapsto Hom(A,X)$ only preserve monomorphisms in general. In fact such a functor preserves epimorphisms if and only if the representing object $A$ is projective (by definition).

For example, in the category of abelian groups, consider the surjective map $ \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$
and the functor represented by $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Giving a map $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to A$ is the same thing as choosing an element of $A$ whose order divides $2$, so that $Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} ,\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but $Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\{0\}$, thus the induced map between the two cannot be surjective.

Comment: I understand now, the "inverse" to the surjective morphism isn't necessarily a morphism in the category. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in what category you are working but there are many where this property does not hold.

In an abelian category, the objects $G$ for which the exactness of $\mbox{Hom}(G,-)$ hold are called **projective** objects.

See this discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47408/289217).